# how to send user input to php, excute sql command and display output from php

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, ajax

my program works like this.
there are three buttons on html page which are linking to three different php files which result in xml,
result are based on fixed sql command in oracle.
when user click on one of the button eg.

```
    <p><input class="fetchSeries" type="button" value="CurrValue">  
  <a href="connectyf.php"> </a>  
  <span></span>
  </p>
```

it will then trigger the below ajax, and to plot a graph on html page

```
 $("input.fetchSeries").click(function () {
     var button = $(this);  
     var dataurl = button.siblings('a').attr('href');
     $.ajax({
     url: dataurl,
     type: "GET",
 cache: false,
     success: function (data2) {
      $(data2).find('node').each(function(){
      var currV = $(this).find('snv').text();
      var dateT =   ($(this).find('agev').text())*1000;
      var d2 = [];
      d2.push(dateT, currV);
      dataset.push(d2);
      button.siblings('span').text('Fetched '  + ', first point: ' );
     })
   data.push(dataset);
   $.plot(placeholder, data,options);
   dataset = [];
  }
    }); 
  });
```

sql command :

```
   $sql = "SELECT TO_CHAR(DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS DATETIME, PRESENTSTATE
   FROM T00000000_01080413 WHERE DATETIME BETWEEN '04-OCT-11' AND '15-OCT-11' ";
```

what i need to do now is place four user input field and one button, click the button to control the sql command, something should be like this in php page if im not mistaken

```
$sql = "SELECT TO_CHAR(DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS '$_POST[datetime]', '$_POST[vall]' FROM T00000000_01080413 WHERE DATETIME BETWEEN '$_POST[startdate]' AND '$_POST[enddate]' ";
```

now im a bit headache how do i use the user input as sql command and plot the graph once i click the button?

is it may use the input[name=startdate]; something like that?
soooo headache now.please inspire me....
thx so much in advance

```
  <form method="post" > 
    <div> 
        <input type="text" class="form-text required" value="" size="15" id="edit-name" name="startd" maxlength="60"> 
        <input type="text" class="form-text required" value="" size="15" id="edit-name" name="endd" maxlength="60"> 
        <input type="text" class="form-text required" value="" size="15" id="edit-name" name="pname" maxlength="60"> 
        <input type="text" class="form-text required" value="" size="15" id="edit-name" name="val" maxlength="60"> 
      <input class="fetchSeries" type="button" value="draw graph!"/> 
    </div>
  </form> 














$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "connectyf1.php",
  data: "startdate="+startdt+"&enddate="+enddt+"&tablename="+tname+"&parameter"+param,
  success: function(grapHtml){

    $("#graph").append(graphHtml); 

 $.ajax({
               url: "connectyf1.php",
               type: "GET",
       cache: false,
               success: function (data2) { 
  $(data2).find('node').each(function(){
  var currV = $(this).find('snv').text();
  var dateT =   ($(this).find('agev').text())*1000;
  var d2 = [];
  d2.push(dateT, currV);
   dataset.push(d2);
  button.siblings('span').text('Fetched '  + ', first point: ' );
  })
   data.push(dataset);
    $.plot(placeholder, data,options);
        dataset = [];
  }
    });

   }
  });
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand your question. are you looking for the jquery selector to select an input element by its name-attribute ? That 's done with $('input[name="startd"]')

Comment: I dont really understand what is the problem? you want to send values to the php and return a graph?

Comment: $('input[name="startd"]') yup thats part of the answer i've looking for...the tough part is how and where do i use $('input[name="startd"]') to send user input to php as part of the sql command?

Comment: i believe in php file i can just simply use @post to get the date sent from html...but how can i send...?

Comment: Still not sure if i follow, but in your example, you use $.ajax with type="GET". This means that you send your values as get parameters in the url, like www.example.com/connectyf.php?startd=2011-10-17. In php, you are able to access get parameters in the $_GET[] array. $_POST[] array is for a submission with method 'post', not 'get'

Comment: can i send multi get parameters like  www.example.com/connectyf.php?startd=2011-10-17?enddate=2011-10-18?tablename=example?value=currvalue?

Comment: if that is possible then i will able to access those input with $_GET['startd'];$_GET['enddate'];$_GET['tablename'];$_GET['value']; right?

Comment: yes, but you'll have to seperate them with '&' except the first parameter. example: http://example.com?param1=500&param2=600&param3=700&param4=800  .

Comment: but how do i "send" those value? thats what made me headache..i've thought about using  xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?q="+str,true); but is it will only print the php echo but not sending the value?

Comment: my page now able to plot the graph by clicking a button. graph value is a hardcoded php file. what i want is make it not hardcode. user can make their own sql command by input some parameter..

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me again. Maybe you should reformat your question above. Be as specific as possible, but cut it down to the essence of your problem. More people will understand your problem and will be able to help you.

Comment: thx so much for helping and give advaice :D  ...try this....i write a sql command on html page, click a button, and executed result will show on the same page....

Comment: so..this will have ajax and php involved right? i know the php part, but ajax is what i dont know :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jquery (version 1.5 or higher) you can make an ajax call by using this:

```
var startd = $('input[name="startd"]').val();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: "startd="+startd+"&location=Boston",
  success: function(grapHtml){
    $("#graph").append(graphHtml);
  }
});
```

This makes a post request to some.php. This file will receive $_POST['startd'] and $_POST['location'] values.

Comment: again my greatest thank for your help and time. but not quite sure about the $("#graph").append(graphHtml);? ive seen ppl do $('body div').text(data); . is it a function to print out result?