# how to perform sql command on html page with user input field, and show result on the same page

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, ajax

i write a command, or i fill up parameter value from user input field. click the button, send this command to php and send resultant value back to html to display.
for example. on html page :

```
select ___ from ____,
```

two available input field i fill up with "tablenameone" and "valueone". then, result will be printed on html text field on the same page.

what i do know is those value can be sent(perhaps) as in such format

```
$('input[name="talbename"]') 
$('input[name="value"]')
example.com?tablename=tablenameone&value=valueone
```

and from php side i use

```
 $sql="SELECT '$_GET['value']' FROM '$_GET['tablename']';
```

what i dont know is that....how exactly should i perform this in a click function? its for sure using ajax. but how can i produce  example.com?tablename=tablenameone&value=valueone
and where should i put $('input[name="value"]')

thanks in advance :D

Comment: Nice [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com) on top of the PHP syntax error...

Comment: Definitely agree with Marc B, giant security hole!

Comment: So you're letting the user decide which field select, where to do that, and without sanitizing? I don't know how long your db will last

Comment: guys..lol good joke from ur link marc B....i just made my question simplified so i can start from basic....i actually planned to use selection instead...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794055/how-to-send-user-input-to-php-excute-sql-command-and-display-output-from-php     here is my original question...took me some time to explain my actual problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeming as though noone has actually answered the question (although they are all good points, I will assume there is a reason for you doing this), I will answer:

```
$('form[name=formname]').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    var tablename = $('input[name="tablename"]').val();
    var value = $('input[name="value"]').val();
    $.get("example.php?tablename="+tablename+"&value="+value, function(data){
         $('body div').text(data);
    })
});
```

PHP:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT '$_GET['value']' FROM '$_GET['tablename']'")or die(mysql_error());
$sqlOutput = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($sqlOutput);
echo "</pre>";
```

Obviously replace `formname` with your form name, `body div` with the name of the element you want the output to go in and all other identifiers replaced where seen fit. Then change the output in the PHP to suit your needs.

Again, do bear in mind the posts regarding SQLi, because you have yourself a very serious problem there.

Comment: can i use $("input.classname").click(function (e) { instead? preventDefault is for not going to the php page isnt it? :D

Comment: sure, however if the `e.preventDefault` on the `submit` it will work fine as it prevents the form from actually submitting and then handles all the `AJAX`

Answer (score 5):

You must not use direct input in your queries as you will be open to [SQL injection attacks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

```
$sql="SELECT '$_GET['value']' FROM '$_GET['tablename']';
```

Instead, use the following:

```
$column = $_GET['value'];
$table = $_GET['tablename'];
$sql = sprintf("SELECT %s FROM %s;",
             mysql_real_escape_string($column),
             mysql_real_escape_string($table));
```

Although you are still exposing too much "inside information" by giving people a page that tells them all of your table and column names!

Anyway, here is a complete example;

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select Data</legend>
        <p><label>Table<br>
        <select name="table">
            <option value="tblStudents">Students</option>
        </select></label></p>
        <p><label>Table<br>
        <select name="column">
            <option value="firstname">First Name</option>
            <option value="lastname">Last Name</option>
        </select></label></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("servername:3306", "user", "password") or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

mysql_select_db("databasename");  

$column = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['column']);
$table =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['table']);
$sql = sprintf("SELECT %s FROM %s;",
        $column,
        $table);

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

echo '<ul>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo '<li>' . $row[$column] . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';

mysql_close($connection); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You really want to make sure you are not open to SQL injection.

You could use mysql prepared statements

or

use the php function `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['value'])`

Read this thread:
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

I'm not sure what you mean by the click function.